# Turtle clashing with Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, turtle-graphics

I have to files: one is called curve, and the other one main. In main i am trying to open a button window, then whenever the button is pressed. it starts drawing something over in curve using turtle. This is the simplified script:

main:

```
 import tkinter

    master = tkinter.Toplevel()

    def callback():
        print("click!")
        master.withdraw()
        b.quit()
        import curve

    b = tkinter.Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
    b.pack()
    tkinter.mainloop()
```

curve:

```
  import turtle

  turtle.bgpic("somefile.gif")
  #do some other stuff
```

however when i run this i get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/MYNAME/PycharmProjects/hilbert/main.py", line 7, in callback
    import curve
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\PycharmProjects\hilbert\curve.py", line 3, in <module>
    turtle.bgpic("images/processed.gif")
  File "<string>", line 1, in bgpic
  File "C:\Python34\lib\turtle.py", line 1474, in bgpic
    self._setbgpic(self._bgpic, self._bgpics[picname])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\turtle.py", line 737, in _setbgpic
    self.cv.itemconfig(item, image=image)
  File "<string>", line 1, in itemconfig
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2380, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1261, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Comment: I stll have no idea how this works, but i have managed to get my own code  working without the bgpic(). Also: i know that it should be more like `root = tkinter.Tk()`
`root.withdraw()  `  
`master = tkinter.Toplevel(root)  `
`master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)` but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since turtle is implemented with tkinter, you're walking a tightrope when you mix the two.  This rework of your code seems to do what you describe, including the `bgpic()` call:

**main.py**

```
import tkinter
import turtle

turtle.Screen()
root = tkinter.Toplevel()

def callback():
    print("click!")
    root.withdraw()
    b.quit()
    import curve

b = tkinter.Button(root, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

**curve.py**

```
import turtle

turtle.bgpic('somefile.gif')

# do some other stuff

turtle.circle(100)

turtle.mainloop()
```